# Is there a way to replace the default X11 menubar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, x11

I have an X11 application for Mac OS X 10.5 and higher and I'm trying to write a wrapper around it to give it a more native feel.
Does anyone know if it's possible to replace the default X11 menubar with my own custom menubar so that it displays whenever the application window is open?
And if so, how would I go about doing it with Cocoa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no. X11 does not allow you to modify its menu bar. It would be difficult as there is first of all no X call to set a menu bar (that is provided by toolkits) but also because Apple wants to discriminate between native apps and those using X11 as a "hack" solution to provide Mac compatibility.

To do this, you'll need to modify X11.app/XQuartz.app's source code and add this functionality yourself. Keep in mind, though, that unless you are careful your solution won't work on other X servers due to the fact that X does not provide menu bar functionality.

For information on X server source code for Mac, see [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/Releases).

Comment: Ah well, I guess I'll have to simply put the menu items into the dock menu of my wrapper. Not the most elegant solution, but it'll do.